# jQuery - Scroll Function Keeps Triggering: Only Once Please

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery function which triggers `aTestEvent()` when the user scrolls horizontally past 500 pixels:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).scrollLeft() >= 500){
           aTestEvent();
 }});
```

Here's the issue: I only want `aTestEvent()` to be triggered once! However, every time the user scrolls back to the beginning of the page and then again past 500 pixels, `aTestEvent()` is triggered again.

How can we adjust the above code so that the trigger **only occurs for the first time** the user scrolls past 500 pixels?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `on` and `off` methods:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if( $(this).scrollLeft() >= 500 ) {
        $(document).off('scroll');
        aTestEvent();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kacd/

Please Note: This code snippet could "off" all the scroll event available on a particular page but to scroll off only intended scroll handler without disturbing other scroll handlers, we can use a namespace.   Namespaces are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one name needs to match.

```
$(document).on('name1.scroll', function() {
    if( $(this).scrollLeft() >= 500 ) {
        $(document).off('name1.scroll');
        aTestEvent();
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardtu/3kacd/57/**

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you very much. Will accept once I can.

Comment: Another handy trick is the lesser-known .one() method. http://api.jquery.com/one/
Very useful every once in a while, but it wouldn't technically work for this because of the if() statement - it would only fire once, even if the if condition was false.

Comment: @undefined why did you put .off before the event?

Comment: @raam86 `off` unbinds the handler registered by `on` method, as OP wants to stop listening to the event I have used `off`.

Comment: of course. but why not: console.log('aTestEvent');  $(document).off('scroll');

So it turns off after the event is fired. This is genuine intrigue

Comment: @raam86 Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: You turned the event off before it was fired. you could write the line the calls the one time event before $(document).off('scroll')
Why do you stop listening before the event is fired?

Comment: @raam86 Well, I didn't, the `off` is called when the condition is met within the `scroll` handler, please reread the question, jQuery `off` documentation and check the fiddle in my answer.