# How to execute this Jquery code only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Firstly, sorry if my english is bad, I'm french !

So, I have a script that executes reached a certain level of scroll in the page. This script is a number counter which starts when the scroll makes it visible (In the middle of a onepage website).
However I do not know how to make this script will run once.

So when I get to the section containing the counter , this one begins to reach a specific number . But when I scroll again , the counter restarts from 0.
I think I have find the loop, but my knowledge in Js is not good enough to modify it... Can you help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: some context would help ... like showing the code you only want to run once, in context

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: You could use on/off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782753/jquery-scroll-function-keeps-triggering-only-once-please

Answer (score 1):

Using cookies.
Use a cookie and set a flag when first time scroll happens.
next time check for flag is set if yes the script should not execute.

Using document.off may affect other ajax calls if present.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. You can do your stuff after visitor scrolls more than 40% of the page content.

```
var f=0; //assign flag as global variable
 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

        var wintop = jQuery(window).scrollTop(), docheight = jQuery(document).height(), winheight = jQuery(window).height();
        var  scrolltrigger = 0.4; /* assign initial value for 40% scroll 

        if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {

            if(f==0) {
            console.log(Scroll reaches 40% of content));
                /*
                    Do your stuff after vistor scroll more than 40% of your page content. And it executes only once.
                */
                f=1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var once = function(){
    //TO DO
    once = function(){};
}

once()
```

Or you can try `jQuery('').one('scroll', callback)` if you want catch event